# Detecting Tiles in Java

Tags: java, swing

My program detects what tile is being clicked and prints it to the console

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestGrid implements MouseListener {

int scl = 50;
JPanel p;

public TestGrid() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("tenprint");
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    frame.setSize(501, 501);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    p = new JPanel() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1234567890L;

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            p.setBackground(Color.black);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1f));
                    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g2.fillRect(x * scl, y * scl, scl, scl);
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2.drawRect(x * scl, y * scl, scl, scl);

                }
            }
        }
    };
    frame.add(p);
    frame.addMouseListener(this);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getClickCount());

    System.out.println("Y: " + e.getY() + "\nX: " + e.getX());

    if (e.getX() <= 50 && e.getY() <= 50) {
        System.out.println("firstSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 50 && e.getY() <= 100) {
        System.out.println("SecondSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 50 && e.getY() <= 150) {
        System.out.println("thirdSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 50 && e.getY() <= 200) {
        System.out.println("fourthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 50 && e.getY() <= 250) {
        System.out.println("fifthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 50 && e.getY() <= 300) {
        System.out.println("sixthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 50 && e.getY() <= 350) {
        System.out.println("seventhSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 50 && e.getY() <= 400) {
        System.out.println("eighthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 50 && e.getY() <= 450) {
        System.out.println("ninthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 50 && e.getY() <= 500) {
        System.out.println("tenthSqaure.");
        // end of column 1

        // start of column 2
    } else if (e.getX() <= 100 && e.getY() <= 50) {
        System.out.println("eleventhSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 100 && e.getY() <= 100) {
        System.out.println("twelthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 100 && e.getY() <= 150) {
        System.out.println("thirteenthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 100 && e.getY() <= 200) {
        System.out.println("fourteenthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 100 && e.getY() <= 250) {
        System.out.println("fifteenthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 100 && e.getY() <= 300) {
        System.out.println("sixteenthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 100 && e.getY() <= 350) {
        System.out.println("seventeenthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 100 && e.getY() <= 400) {
        System.out.println("eighteenthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 100 && e.getY() <= 450) {
        System.out.println("nineteenthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 100 && e.getY() <= 500) {
        System.out.println("twentiethSqaure.");
        // end of column 2

        // start of column 3
    } else if (e.getX() <= 150 && e.getY() <= 50) {
        System.out.println("twentyfirstSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 150 && e.getY() <= 100) {
        System.out.println("twentysecondSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 150 && e.getY() <= 150) {
        System.out.println("twentythirdSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 150 && e.getY() <= 200) {
        System.out.println("twentyfourthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 150 && e.getY() <= 250) {
        System.out.println("twentyfifthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 150 && e.getY() <= 300) {
        System.out.println("twentysixthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 150 && e.getY() <= 350) {
        System.out.println("twentyseventhSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 150 && e.getY() <= 400) {
        System.out.println("twentyeighthSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 150 && e.getY() <= 450) {
        System.out.println("twentyninethSqaure.");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 150 && e.getY() <= 500) {
        System.out.println("thirtiethSqaure.");
        // end of column 3

        // start of column 4
    }

    else if (e.getX() <= 200 && e.getY() <= 50) {
        System.out.println("31");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 200 && e.getY() <= 100) {
        System.out.println("32");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 200 && e.getY() <= 150) {
        System.out.println("33");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 200 && e.getY() <= 200) {
        System.out.println("34");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 200 && e.getY() <= 250) {
        System.out.println("35");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 200 && e.getY() <= 300) {
        System.out.println("36");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 200 && e.getY() <= 350) {
        System.out.println("37");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 200 && e.getY() <= 400) {
        System.out.println("38");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 200 && e.getY() <= 450) {
        System.out.println("39");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 200 && e.getY() <= 500) {
        System.out.println("40");
        // end of column 4

        // start of column 5
    } else if (e.getX() <= 250 && e.getY() <= 50) {
        System.out.println("41");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 250 && e.getY() <= 100) {
        System.out.println("42");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 250 && e.getY() <= 150) {
        System.out.println("43");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 250 && e.getY() <= 200) {
        System.out.println("44");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 250 && e.getY() <= 250) {
        System.out.println("45");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 250 && e.getY() <= 300) {
        System.out.println("46");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 250 && e.getY() <= 350) {
        System.out.println("47");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 250 && e.getY() <= 400) {
        System.out.println("48");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 250 && e.getY() <= 450) {
        System.out.println("49");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 250 && e.getY() <= 500) {
        System.out.println("50");
        // end of column 5

        // start of column 6
    } else if (e.getX() <= 300 && e.getY() <= 50) {
        System.out.println("51");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 300 && e.getY() <= 100) {
        System.out.println("52");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 300 && e.getY() <= 150) {
        System.out.println("53");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 300 && e.getY() <= 200) {
        System.out.println("54");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 300 && e.getY() <= 250) {
        System.out.println("55");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 300 && e.getY() <= 300) {
        System.out.println("56");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 300 && e.getY() <= 350) {
        System.out.println("57");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 300 && e.getY() <= 400) {
        System.out.println("58");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 300 && e.getY() <= 450) {
        System.out.println("59");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 300 && e.getY() <= 500) {
        System.out.println("60.");
        // end of column 6

        // start of column 7
    } else if (e.getX() <= 350 && e.getY() <= 50) {
        System.out.println("60's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 350 && e.getY() <= 100) {
        System.out.println("60's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 350 && e.getY() <= 150) {
        System.out.println("60's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 350 && e.getY() <= 200) {
        System.out.println("60's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 350 && e.getY() <= 250) {
        System.out.println("60's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 350 && e.getY() <= 300) {
        System.out.println("60's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 350 && e.getY() <= 350) {
        System.out.println("60's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 350 && e.getY() <= 400) {
        System.out.println("60's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 350 && e.getY() <= 450) {
        System.out.println("60's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 350 && e.getY() <= 500) {
        System.out.println("70's.");
        // end of column 7

        // start of column 8
    } else if (e.getX() <= 400 && e.getY() <= 50) {
        System.out.println("70's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 400 && e.getY() <= 100) {
        System.out.println("70's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 400 && e.getY() <= 150) {
        System.out.println("70's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 400 && e.getY() <= 200) {
        System.out.println("70's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 400 && e.getY() <= 250) {
        System.out.println("70's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 400 && e.getY() <= 300) {
        System.out.println("70's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 400 && e.getY() <= 350) {
        System.out.println("70's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 400 && e.getY() <= 400) {
        System.out.println("70's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 400 && e.getY() <= 450) {
        System.out.println("70's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 400 && e.getY() <= 500) {
        System.out.println("80's.");
        // end of column 8

        // start of column 9
    } else if (e.getX() <= 450 && e.getY() <= 50) {
        System.out.println("80's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 450 && e.getY() <= 100) {
        System.out.println("80's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 450 && e.getY() <= 150) {
        System.out.println("80's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 450 && e.getY() <= 200) {
        System.out.println("80's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 450 && e.getY() <= 250) {
        System.out.println("80's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 450 && e.getY() <= 300) {
        System.out.println("80's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 450 && e.getY() <= 350) {
        System.out.println("80's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 450 && e.getY() <= 400) {
        System.out.println("80's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 450 && e.getY() <= 450) {
        System.out.println("80's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 450 && e.getY() <= 500) {
        System.out.println("90's.");
        // end of column 9

        // start of column 10
    } else if (e.getX() <= 500 && e.getY() <= 50) {
        System.out.println("90's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 500 && e.getY() <= 100) {
        System.out.println("90's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 500 && e.getY() <= 150) {
        System.out.println("90's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 500 && e.getY() <= 200) {
        System.out.println("90's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 500 && e.getY() <= 250) {
        System.out.println("90's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 500 && e.getY() <= 300) {
        System.out.println("90's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 500 && e.getY() <= 350) {
        System.out.println("90's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 500 && e.getY() <= 400) {
        System.out.println("90's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 500 && e.getY() <= 450) {
        System.out.println("90's");
    } else if (e.getX() <= 500 && e.getY() <= 500) {
        System.out.println("100's.");
        // end of column 10
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new TestGrid();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // do nothing here
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // do nothing here
}

}
```

Please let me know how awful this is and how to avoid using ~100 if statements

Comment: Are the tiles identical by design, or can they be different?

Comment: They can be different @TimSparrow

Comment: Please don't include solution in the question. You accepted the answer so this is enough to show that it's a good review.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The entirety of the if/else statements are redundent if we consider that if we divide the current location by the `tile_size` we get the correct tile number

```
int tile_size = 50;

int tile_x = e.getX() / tile_size;
int tile_y = e.getY() / tile_size;
System.out.println(String.format("square %d%d", tile_x, tile_y));
```

*I am not a Java Developer so pardon my Java*

Comment: Note that this will only work for non-negative coordinates. (Which is fine in this case)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of implementing `MouseListener`, you can use the [MouseAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) class to implement only the method you need.

```
frame.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        //your implementation  
    }
});
```